# "as" as a preposition or conjunction

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

> 1. Does ‘start’ mean the same **as** ‘begin’ in English?
> 2. My new car is the same model **as** my old one.
> 3. Tom’s house is the same size **as** mine.
> 4. You have the same pen **as** I have.

In sentence one to three, "as" is a preposition and in sentence 4, "as" is a conjunction. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In the first three sentences, "as" is followed by a noun phrase, so it is a *preposition*.

In the fourth sentence, "as" is followed by a complete clause, so it is a *conjunction*.

Also, it's worth noting that "as" can be an *adverb*, when followed by an adjective, adverb, or comparative such as "much" or "many."

Comment: Thank you very much!